# Drupal Views: Adding Edit button and other buttons per item

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I've setup a view in drupal that lists items like this:

```
IMAGE 1 | IMAGE 2 | IMAGE 3 | IMAGE 4
 desc   |  desc   |   desc  |  desc
```

where "desc" is, you guessed it, a description of the node. What I need is to end up with something like this:

```
IMAGE 1 | IMAGE 2 | IMAGE 3 | IMAGE 4
 desc   |  desc   |   desc  |  desc
 EDIT   |  EDIT   |  EDIT   |  EDIT  
 ACTION | ACTION  | ACTION  | ACTION
```

Where EDIT goes to the edit page of the various nodes. Also, the ACTION signifies a button that I want to appear underneath the items that navigates to a page, let's call it http://www.mysite.com/action and takes the id as a parameter to end up with something like this: http://www.mysite.com/action/1.

I hope this all makes sense.

The pain in the ass way to solving this is to create a theme file views-view-NAME.tpl.php and manipulate the $rows variable. I just think there must be a better way and I'm obviously just missing something.

So, does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add *links* and then style them as buttons (if you really need it to look like a button) by doing something like this:

Add the following fields to your view:

- Node: Edit Link (this will take care of permissions for you, only displaying a link for users that have access to edit)
- Node: Nid

In order to get that second field to be an arbitrary link containing the node ID, select the *Output this field as a link* option when configuring the field. In the *Link path* box, enter the desired link, something like this:

```
action/[nid]
```

or, you can use an absolute url

```
http://www.example.com/action/[nid]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8, I built the Views Any Route module, which lets you create buttons based on routes: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_any_route . The main use for the module is that access checking is included in the construction of the link, which would otherwise require a custom field, or Views Field View, etc.

In this case, if you use the Devel module, you can look up the "routes info" and find the correct route for a node path. You then create the Any Route button for that route, and pass the nid as a parameter (i.e. node={{ nid }}).